# Updating script to find a new type of file

Tags: applescript

I need to update the script shown below to find a new file type and naming system and have no idea what I'm doing. It use to pull a file named `DQXXXXX1.eps` and placed in the listed location.  The new files are `XXXXX_random.pdf`.  The random in the file name is several series of numbers that change for each file.  The important numbers are the first 5, I would like the script to pull all files in that initial location and place into the other location.

The current script is:

```
set DQfolder to alias "Prepress:ArtFiles:00-Logos A to Z:1-DQ:"

tell application "Finder"   
    display dialog "enter number" default answer ""  
    set theNum to text returned of result as string  
    --try  
    move alias (DQfolder & "DQ" & theNum & ".eps" as string) to "Macintosh HD:__DQ Incoming:" with replacing
    --on error {}  
    --move alias (DQfolder & "DQ" & theNum & ".tif") to "Macintosh HD:__DQ Incoming:" with replacing
    --end try

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your script like the following. You have a few things that need to be fixed...

1. Basically you are adding the strings wrong. You need to first coerce DQfolder to a string before you can add the other strings to it.  The way you are doing it can't work because DQfolder is an alias so you can't add other strings to it until you coerce the alias to a string.
2. the folder path in your command has to be an alias-type file or a folder specification. As such you need to put the word "alias" or "folder" in front of it. A string path will not work. Applescript rarely works with string paths.
3. "display dialog" is not a Finder command and as such you don't need to put it in the Finder block of code.
4. "text returned" from your display dialog command is already "text" so you do not need to coerce it to a string. That's why it's called "text" returned... even if you entered a number it's class is still text.

Of course I can't check this code because I don't have files at those paths, but it should work. Good luck...

```
set DQfolder to alias "Prepress:ArtFiles:00-Logos A to Z:1-DQ:"

display dialog "enter number" default answer ""  
set theNum to text returned of result

tell application "Finder"
    move alias ((DQfolder as text) & "DQ" & theNum & ".eps") to alias "Macintosh HD:__DQ Incoming:" with replacing
end tell
```